# How to merge two query in web Application runtime and execute new created query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, web-applications

I have a web application. I want to merge two queries and then send the new query to the database to run. I want to know is it possible or not?
Suppose **user1** execute ***query1*** and **user2** execute ***query2***. Is it possible to merge query1 and query2 in the runtime by the application and execute created new query on the database?

---

**User1**: execute ***query1***: `select * from tblEmployee where name=value1`

**User2**: execute ***query2***: `Select * from tblEmployee where name=value2`

---

I want to create a new query like this:

**new query**: `select * from tblEmployee where name IN (value1, value2)`

Given that created different sessions for each user on the web application, is it possible to merge two user query that executes on application? can an array be defined as a buffer and queries stored there?if yes, please how?

Comment: Seriously why do you want to do this? Why try and build a query from 2 separate sessions? And how would your marshal them, given they will both be requested asynchronously? Seems a lot of work for no gain?

Comment: I agree with @DaleK I don't really see what this gets you and seems like a very complicated solution to your problem.  Speaking of which, what is the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @Dalek , kevin Dear,I am trying to develop a new technique for outsourcing data in the public cloud and also be able to ensure data security. Therefore, I want to prevent data leakage by combining fake values. The issue is very long.
Now in this question I just want to know if it is possible in practical to merge the query value of two users with each other? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's possible as user 1 and user 2 would not only be executing the queries in different sessions, but also at different times (even if by miliseconds). If you know how close the two requests will be, you could create a temporary table (TmpTable) and append the results of each query to it.

```
INSERT INTO TmpTable select * from tblEmployee where name=value1
INSERT INTO TmpTable select * from tblEmployee where name=value2
```

Then delay by a second or two and run a simple

```
SELECT * FROM TmpTable
```

and each user will get the same results.

To get more complicated you could set some flag in a seperate table to check both queries have executed before running the SELECT.

Comment: Is there no way in global.asax? For example, can not an array be defined as a buffer in application_Start method or something else that can do this?thanks @Anguswalker .